# Run Istio getting started, get error CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: istio

Follow Istio getting started (https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/).

- installed istio
- deployed BookInfo
- service and pods running
- run kubectl exec ..
- got error "upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. retried and the latest reset reason: remote connection failure, transport failure reason: TLS_error:|268435581:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED:TLS_error_end:TLS_error_end"

Any suggestion?

expect to get Simple Bookstore App from curl command